# Automake: how to handle global and local 'make check' effectively?

Tags: automated-tests, automake

In a larger project, I have set up `./tests/Makefile.am` to run a number of tests when I call `make check`. The file `global_wrapper.c` contains the setup / breakdown code, and it calls test functions implemented in several subdirectories.

```
TESTS = global_test

check_PROGRAMS = global_test

global_test_SOURCES = global_wrapper.c foo/foo_test.c bar/bar_test.c
```

Works great. But the tests take a long time, so I would like to be able to optionally execute only tests from a single subdir. This is how I did it at first.

I added the subdirectories:

```
SUBDIRS = foo bar
```

In the subdirectories, I added local wrappers and `Makefile.am`'s:

```
TESTS = foo_test

check_PROGRAMS = foo_test

# the foo_test.c here is of course the same as in the global Makefile.am
foo_test_SOURCES = foo_wrapper.c foo_test.c
```

This, too, works great - when I call `make check` in the subdirectory `foo`, only the foo tests are executed.

**However**, when I now call `make check` in `./tests`, *all tests are executed twice*. Once through `global_test`, and once through the local test programs.

If I omit the `SUBDIRS` statement in the global `Makefile.am`, the subdirectory makefiles don't get build. If I omit `TESTS` from the local `Makefile.am`'s, `make check` doesn't do anything for the local directories.

I'm not that familiar with automake, but I am pretty sure there is some way to solve this dilemma. Can anybody here give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break your tests up.  In your tests/Makefile.am do:

```
TESTS = foo_test bar_test
```

and build foo_test bar_test appropriately with something like

```
foo_test_SOURCES = foo/foo_wrapper.c foo/foo_test.c
bar_test_SOURCES = bar/bar_wrapper.c bar/bar_test.c
```

Now, if you do a raw 'make check', both tests will be run.  If you only want to run one test, you can do that with 'make check TESTS=foo_test' or 'make check TESTS=bar_test' and only the appropriate test will run.  Typically, the Makefile.am lists all the tests that will be run by default in TESTS and the user selects alternate tests at make-time.  Naturally, if you are running the tests a lot, you can 'export TESTS=foo_test' in your shell session and then only type 'make check'.

Comment: Nice tip with setting the environment variable, but it doesn't help with my problem: Having, for the global test run, a summary of *all* tests run at the *end* of the output.

Comment: The Makefile generated by Automake does output a summary at the end.  It tells you 'All 2 tests passed'.  If you want something more explicit, your test should generate the output for you.  See the check unit test framework for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you remove from "global_test" any test that is already executed in a subdirectory?  (Just so they simply don't get executed twice.)

Comment: The tests generate lots of output, and print their summary at the end. Executing the subdirectory tests in sequence would drown the actual results in that output, which is why having all tests bundled into one global suite is useful (you get a proper one-glance summary at the end of the output).

Comment: My tests usually have a verbose option.  When they are run from make check, they are silent: there standard output is redirected to a log file, and only the conclusion is written out stderr (with a mention of the log file in case of failure).  This way the important information is not hidden in the output.   When the tests are run manually, they are verbose and standard output goes to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could maybe overwrite the `check` rule at the top-level to define an environment variable:

```
check:
        DISABLE_SUBTESTS=1 make check-recursive
```

and then test `DISABLE_SUBTESTS` in your sub-directories to decide whether to actually run the tests or not.

(Personally, I'd rather arrange to work in the existing `make check` framework by concealing the output of my tests, rather than overwriting the produced rules like this.)

Comment: This sounds interesting; as I said, I am not that familiar with Automake and was unaware that you could overwrite rules. (And wouldn't have known baout check-recursive anyway.) I will check this out.